# Can you have non class objects in PHP as you can with JavaScript etc?

Tags: php

I have the following data structure. I need an array of movies. Each movie has a title, rating and year.

```
Movies:

--Title = "The Hobbit";
--Rating = 7;
--Year   = 2012;

--Title = "Lord of the rings";
--Rating = 5;
--Year   = 2001;
```

If this was JavaScript you would have an array of objects:

```
const movies = [{
  title:"The Hobbit",
  rating:7,
  year:2012
},
{
  title:"Lord of the rings",
  rating:5,
  year:2001
}]
```

How do you model this in PHP? I know that you could create a class of Movie and each movie would be an instance of this class, but is this required? Can you just have non-class objects like with JavaScript?

Comment: In PHP you can use associative arrays.

Comment: https://repl.it/join/tqikldbw-judemanutd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways:

Associative arrays:

```
$movies = [
[
  "title" => "The Hobbit",
  "rating" => 7,
  "year" => 2012
],
[
"title" => "Lord of the rings",
  "rating" => 5,
  "year" => 2001
]
];
```

Or you use an object of type \stdClass.
Easiest definition:

```
$movie1 = (object)[
  "title" => "The Hobbit",
  "rating" => 7,
  "year" => 2012
];
```

Or you do it this way:

```
$movie1 = new \stdClass();
$movie1->title = "The Hobbit";
```

Access works like that:

```
echo $movie1->title; // The Hobbit
```

You can collect them again in $movies:

```
$movies = [$movie1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely can! Objects extend a base \stdClass which would behave similarly to your description. A great example of this is the json_decode() method defaults.

To create one of these objects from scratch, either invoke the \stdClass constructor, or just typecast an array to `(object)`.

Based on your example JSON, here's the use of a \stdClass in PHP, both from serialisation and instantiating your own objects.

```php
<?php

$decoded = json_decode('[{
        "title": "The Hobbit",
        "rating": 7,
        "year": 2012
    },
    {
        "title": "Lord of the rings",
        "rating": 5,
        "year": 2001
    }
]');
print_r($decoded);
echo $decoded[0]->title . PHP_EOL;

print_r(new \stdClass());
print_r((object)[]);
print_r((object)['example_public_property' => 'example_value']);
```